# jquery prepend + fadeIn

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-animate

I have this code:

```
$.ajax({
        url : url,
        data : {ids : JSON.stringify(jsonids), hotel_id: hotel_id},
        success : function(response)
        {
            $('#be-images ul').prepend(response).fadeIn('slow');
        },
        dataType: 'html'
    });
```

but the fade In does not work...I want the content to be prepended and faded in...how will I do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Assuming `response` is HTML then try this:

```
$(response).hide().prependTo("#be-images ul").fadeIn("slow");
```

When you do it this way:

```
$('#be-images ul').prepend(response).fadeIn('slow');
```

the thing you're actually fading in is the result of the initial selector (the list at the front), which is already visible.

Comment: both cletus and nick, your ways are awesome.. i stumbled upon the same problem and both of your ways work like a breeze... thanks...

Comment: @cletus : I've same problem but my data is json array. I uses .each function and trying to prepend but it doesn't show any data prepending - `var li = '<li>'+item.img+'</li>';$('.twitter-list').prepend(li).hide().fadeIn("fast");`

Answer (score 42):

+1 to cletus, but I just wanted to highlight the other way you could do it.

```
$('#be-images ul').prepend(
    $(response).hide().fadeIn('slow')
);
```

Comment: this works well cause it doesn't hide the element to prepend to, only the element being prepended

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
HTML

```
<button>Add</button>
<div id="data"></div>
```

Jquery:

```
$('button').click(function() {
  $('#data').prepend('<div class="item">Test</div>'"');
    $("#data .item:first-child").hide();
   $("#data .item:first-child").fadeIn();
});
```

Live Demo: **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yqjfoznr/)**