# jQuery. Prepend with fadeIn (error)

Tags: jquery

I've used code from here [jquery prepend + fadeIn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906066/jquery-prepend-fadein)

Without `fadeIn` it works

```
function updateResult(data) {
$('#test').prepend(
    html
);
}
```

But with `fadeIn` works only when data contains one `div` tag,

```
$('#test').prepend(
    $(html).hide().fadeIn('slow')
);
```

otherwise FireFox returns error

```
uncaught exception: [Exception... "Could not convert JavaScript argument arg 0 [nsIDOMViewCSS.getComputedStyle]" nsresult: "0x80570009 (NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_CONVERT_JS)" location: "JS frame :: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js :: <TOP_LEVEL> :: line 16" data: no]
```

How it possible rewrite this code?

**Upd.**
In my situation I've solved it this way

```
data = data.replace(/(?:(?:\r\n|\r|\n)\s*)/gi, '');
$(data).hide().prependTo('#test').fadeIn('slow');
```

After removing line breaks works as should

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be in **linebreaks**.

After reading this thred [Common sources of unterminated string literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227552/common-sources-of-unterminated-string-literal) I get a hind. The server return html code where tags located each on new line, so when \n and space between tags were removed this error disappeared.

Here an example http://jsfiddle.net/gMWFD/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(html).hide().prependTo('#test').fadeIn('slow');
```

You probably cannot use animation methods when the element is not added to the DOM.

Comment: @Tuco: Then it is something else, because it works in Firefox for me: http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/duM7a/ You could also try to change the order of the calls: `$(html).prependTo('#test').hide().fadeIn('slow');` though this might result in flickering.

Comment: maybe it is something with CSS, because yours code does not use it, my does and in error there is nsIDOMViewCSS.getComputedStyle

Answer (score 1):

Testing this code in Firefox and Chrome. I haven't tested with AJAX:

**HTML**

```
<div id="be-images">
    <ul>
        <li>lista</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<button type="button">button</button>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$('button').click(function(){
$('#be-images ul').prepend(
    $('<p>response</p>').hide().fadeIn(2000)
);
});
```